# Unable to assign calendar ID iteratively to extract events from google calendar

Tags: events, calendar, google-calendar-api, extract, spreadsheet

I have been trying to create a working script to extract events from different people calendar. Access is available to read the events.

I have the IDs in a different sheet("Cals2Extract") in the range A2: B4 Column Header A(Cal_ID) and B(Active).

While I'm able to extract events from the first name in the column A2, I'm unable to iterate through the second and third name in column A (A3, A4....).

Extracted events are written in a different sheet (EventCal).

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NUGPUxBUsivYD9c0irdAQV79Ao90caaf8EEMoKyno2M/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help is appreciated.

```
function Get(){

var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID of the sheet")
var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Cals2Extract");
var sheetArr=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
var values = range.getValues();
var ColIndexmap = {};
var mycal="";
var cal="";

Logger.log(sheet);

Logger.log (sheetArr);

for (var row in values) {
  for (var col in values[row]) {
  ColIndexmap[values[row][col]]=parseInt(col);
    }}

for(var i=1;i<sheetArr.length;i++){
mycal ="";
cal ="";

Logger.log(sheetArr.length);

Logger.log(i);

mycal=sheetArr[i][ColIndexmap["Cal_ID"]];

Logger.log(mycal);

cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

Logger.log(cal);

if(sheetArr[i][ColIndexmap["Active"]] != ""){


var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("November 1, 2018 00:00:00 CST"), new 
Date("November 14, 2018 23:59:59 CST"), {search: ''});


var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("EventCal");

sheet1.clearContents();  

Logger.log(sheet1);
```

// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below

```
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", 
"Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", 
"Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All 
Day Event", "Recurring Event"]]
var range = sheet1.getRange(1,1,1,14);
range.setValues(header);
```

// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)

```
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';

var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), 
events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), 
myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), 
events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), 
events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), 
events[i].isRecurringEvent()]];
var range=sheet1.getRange(row,1,1,14);
range.setValues(details);

var cell=sheet1.getRange(row,7);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ 
')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
cell.setNumberFormat('.00');

     }
   }
  } 
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: In order to understand correctly your situation, can you add more information? 1. About ``I'm unable to iterate through the second and third name in column A (A3, A4....).``, does an error occur or ? Can you explain the detail of this? 2. Can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information. I think that these will help users think of your solution.

Comment: 1. No error occurs: I'm trying to assign calendar ID dynamically to my variable var mycal; only the first ID in A1 gets extracted. Ideally I want the next ID in A2 to get assigned to mycal and get the events extracted until the list ends in column A

2. Edited the question to include Sample sheet. I have included dummy calendar ID for testing purpose which can be replaced with your ID to test.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I saw the sample spreadsheet. In your script, it seems that ``mycal=sheetArr[i][ColIndexmap["Cal_ID"]];`` can have the values from "A2" to "A4". So I couldn't understand about your issue. Can you explain the detail? If I had misunderstood your reply, please tell me.

Comment: The whole code runs only for the first value i.e. A2 and doesn't loop for other values

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. ``mycal=sheetArr[i][ColIndexmap["Cal_ID"]];`` of your sample script can have the values from "A2" to "A4". If I misunderstand your issue, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for trying. The sheetArr contains the values from A2 to A4, but the calendar events are not being extracted for all the values from A2 to A4, the event extraction happens only for the first value